# How to cluster when samples are independent and/or dimensions are not independent for each sample?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

In machine learning, one can use Euclidean distance to measure a cluster

$$
\mu\in R^k,
$$

over data points 
$$
\{x_i\}^N_{i=1}\in R^{k\times N},
$$ 
with the measure 
$$
\text{error}_i = ||\mu-x_i||^2_2
$$
The total error can be calculated as
$$
\text{error} = \sum^N_{i=1}error_i
$$ 
To estimate the parameters, one formulates the optimization problem
$$
\min_{\mu_{new}} \big{(}\text{error}\big{)}
$$
This has two underlying assumptions: first, that samples are independent, and, second, that the dimensions are independent for each sample.

Can anyone explain how I should analyze when either or both assumptions are not satisfied?